# Running minimum where accumulator is applied to odd element indices

Tags: numpy

I am trying to write a function which takes the running minimum of two arrays where the accumulator is being added to the second array before taking the minimum in each iteration.

I have the following example:

```
a = np.array([3,  5,  7, 13, 18])
b = np.array([2, 1, 2, 2, 5])
```

I want to output the minimum of each pair and add the result to the second array `b` in the following iteration:

```
np.array(list(itertools.accumulate([(a,b) for a,b in zip(a,b)],lambda acc,x: min(x[0],acc+x[1]),initial=0))[1:])
```

output:

```
array([ 2,  3,  5,  7, 12])
```

can I write this using only numpy?

Comment: As the current results depend on the previous results, there is no vectorized version for this. Plain old for-loop writen in numba will be the way out if you need speed.

Comment: The logic you wrote and the code do not match. Logic: *I want to output the minimum of each pair and add the result to the second array b*. The code is not doing that. Note that in the code, you are doing a cummulative minimum between the array `a` and the sum of the previous minimum and the second array  b. This contradicts your logic